# Dropdownlist Empties on submit button click (Form Post) - Mvc 4 razor using code first approach and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have four dropdownlistfor and a radiobuttonlistfor group. The radiobutton is for location type (which can either be an urban or rural location).

[image]

The first dropdownlistfor is the state which a user must select first before choosing either urban or rural. When the radiobuttonlistfor is selected it triggers a jquery click event which calls an action in my controller to populate the second dropdownlistfor for cities under the selected state and location type.

**Controller**

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetCitiesByStateId(int stateId)
    {
        if (stateId==0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stateId");
        }
        var x = _repository.GetAllCitiesByStateId(stateId);
        var result = (from s in x
                      select new
                      {
                          id = s.id,
                          name = s.CityName
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetRuralArea(int stateId)
    {
        if (stateId == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stateId");
        }

        var x = _repository.GetAllAreaInRural(stateId);
        var result = (from s in x
                      select new
                      {
                          id = s.id,
                          name = s.AreaName
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
State:
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State.ID, Model._State(), "Select")
@Html.RadioButton("UrbanRural", "1", false, new { id = "urban" })
@Html.RadioButton("UrbanRural", "2", false, new { id = "rural" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City.ID, Model._Cities)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AreaRural.ID, Model._AreaRural)
```

**Button Click Code**

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(Registration model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Selpwd = model.Password;
            return View(model);
        }


    }
```

**Issue:**

I observed that when my button is clicked the city or area dropdownlistfor as the case may be empties. How do I retain the content after a postback?

Comment: Can you put the view code snippet also ?

Comment: Hello sampath, I have adjusted the question. I seriously need solution. Thanks

Comment: Where's the code snippet for your button click event ?

Comment: Hi @Sampath, I have added the code for the button click event. Thanks